# Is it dangerous to leave a hose spigot on with a closed nozzle at the end?

Tags: plumbing, water, gardening

Here's the setup: I have a drip system for my plants that's run on a timer attached to my outside hose spigot. The spigot is constantly on, but for about 12 hours a day the timer is closed and no water is flowing through.

Is there a danger of pressure buildup from leaving the faucet on with nowhere for it to go? Will my water bill go up astronomically?

Comment: The pressure can't "build" past the pressure in the source system, so unless the hose between the spigot and the timer valve gives out, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as the attached timer is shut off and no water is flowing the pressure in the water line will be no different than what it would be when the spigot is turned off.

You water bill will reflect how much water that you actually use. The only way it could go up astronomically would be if the timer broke off the spigot or failed in an open mode where water was allowed to flow freely from the spigot for long periods of time.

Comment: As an additional, the only things that will be stressed is the packing gland (faucet stem seal) or if it has it, a vacuum breaker. Modern faucets are built to deal with it, so as long as there isn't any water leaking from underneath the faucet handle, it's all ok.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the answer. I did not think about that it's the same as if the spigot is off but that makes perfect sense. Plumbing/water works is new territory for me. Definitely puts my mind at ease.

Answer (score 0):

In the past i've had two hose spigots seize up when left open all summer, relying on the nozzle on the end of the hose to control the flow.  I'd recommend that you exercise the spigot valve regularly to guard against this.